# Making a list in txt file, for register & login system

Tags: python

I'm new at python, and I'm trying to do a simple Register & Login System with Text file. What I would like to do is:
1.When app is launched ask for user Login or Register. (Done)
2.If user wants to login, we launch the file reader and get the data of the list, from TXT file. (NOT DONE.)
3. If user wants to register we launch the file writer, and write to the list in TXT file to add a user to the registered users list.

In my Opinion the list in the TXT File should look something like this.

Accounts = ["Username" : username, "Password" : password]

```
while True:
    Login_Register = input("Welcome,\nType L for Login, R to Register\n")
    if "L" in Login_Register or "l" in Login_Register:
        Vardas = input("~ Please enter your Username!\n")
        with open(ban_list, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                if Vardas in f.read():
                    Password = input("Please enter your password for user {}".format(Vardas))
                else:
                    print("Account With'in this name does not exist!")
                    continue
        if "R" in Login_Register or "r" in Login_Register:
            break
```

EDIT * 
I thinked abit, and changed a mind about the List in The TXT File should look something like this :
Accounts = ["Username" : Vardas, "Password" : password]

We use Vardas as a variable in the code, so I think this is how its done.

Comment: What exactly is your question? By the way, please don't save the passwords in plaintext, use a hash algorithm (at least md5) to encrypt it. Many applications are hacked every day very quickly because of this issue.

Comment: Tom Atix, how could i use this code, and the txt file, with the list. Any example with this code and txt file, with a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does everthing that you have said in your qestion if anything is wrong tell me in the comments

```
check = True
Login_Register = input("Welcome,\nType L for Login, R to Register\n")
if Login_Register == "l" or Login_Register =="L":
    while check:
        with open('accountfile.txt', 'r') as f:
            username1 = input("Enter your username: ")
            password1 = input("Enter your password: ")
            for line in f:
                if("Username:"+username1+" Password:"+password1) == line.strip():
                    print("you are logged in")
                    check = False
                    break;
                else:
                    print("Username or password does not exist")

elif Login_Register == "r" or Login_Register == "R":
    f = open("accountfile.txt","a+")
    username2 = input("~ Please enter your Username!\n")
    password2 = input("~ Please enter your password!\n")
    f.write(f"\nUsername:{username2} Password:{password2}\n")
    f.close()
    print("username and password has been made")
```

Comment: What does the check = True does?

Comment: @JamesSmith It just a loop so that if you get the username or password wrong it loops it until you get the details right and when they get the username and password correct you add `break` to get out of the loop

Comment: Only one problem, that this script is re-writing the line, if it is in the text file, when you add another account it rewrites current

Comment: @JamesSmith I have fixed the that problem, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The list you have provided

`["Username" : Vardas, "Password" : password]`

is not a valid python list, you will need to use a dictionary which is like this:

`{"Username" : Vardas, "Password" : password}`

As for storing passwords in a .txt file is not a great idea, you should look into getting a database for example [Google's Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) and read up on the python package `firebase` which you can get from `pip install firebase`

Hope this helps.